# Select all files in a folder and subfolders with OSQuery

Tags: windows, osquery

Shouldn’t it be possible to select a files in a folder and its subfolders with the query in OSQuery:
`SELECT path FROM file WHERE directory LIKE '/Users/%';`

That returns no results at all. What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with

```
SELECT path FROM file WHERE path LIKE '/Users/%%';
```

But be warned that this is going to do a traversal of the entire filesystem below `/Users`, so it's going to take a while to run and return a huge number of results.

Comment: Resulted in no rows returned

Comment: This may be a TCC/PPPC issue, since the first directory it would try to enumerate in a clean home folder would be Desktop - for testing this with osqueryi, you'd want to make sure you've allowed Terminal (or iTerm/whatever app you use) Full Disk Access in System Preferences -> Security -> Privacy tab (all the way on the right).